# ThreadPooling in pyspark seems to sum the contents of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am using Threadpooling to try to parallelize multiple for loops that I have in my pyspark code.
However, it seems that when using the `reduce` function at the end, it is simply summing the contents of the resulting list of dataframes.
Here is the code I am using:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

days=[180,5]
    def run_threads(iterr):
        for a in range(len(datepaths)-iterr, len(datepaths)-(iterr-1)):
            path="s3://" + datepaths[a] + "/"
            date_inpath.append(path)
        uva=spark.read.option("basePath",inpath).parquet(*date_inpath)\
        .select(*uvakeepcols)\
        .filter((col('RESULT').isNotNull()))\
        .dropDuplicates()
        uva1=uva.groupBy('SEQ_ID','TOOL_ID')\
        .agg(f.count('RESULT').alias('count'))\
        return uva1

pool = ThreadPool(cpu_count()-1)
df_list = pool.map(run_threads, days)
pool.close()
pool.join()

df=reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, df_list)
```

The above code extracts the results of a particular `SEQ_ID`, `TOOL_ID` combination for 2 days and then counts the number of times the `RESULT` column has values.
When I use thread pooling and compare the counts for the 2 days, I get the following result:

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|count|
+-------+-------+-----+
|2945783|  15032|  574|
|2945783|  15032|  574|
+-------+-------+-----+
```

However, when I extract the data manually from each of the 2 days I get the following result:

From 180 days ago:

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|count(RESULT)|
+-------+-------+-------------+
|2945783|  15032|          285|
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

From 5 days ago:

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
| SEQ_ID|TOOL_ID|count(RESULT)|
+-------+-------+-------------+
|2945783|  15032|          289|
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Somehow the pooling method is adding the two counts `289+285=574`

What exactly is going on here, and is there a way to correct this?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There is no point to threadpool spark. Spark is already a parallel framework, and calling it in parallel may cause problems.

Comment: Understood. But is this expected behavior of Threadpooling whether using Spark or not?